# Is there a better way to recognize and update the in-line style of an element during a swipe gesture?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've been working on a left swipe gesture handler for bubbles in a chat. `touchMove` and `touchStart` would probably be the next step, but right now I'm trying to get this to work just for PC/web.

I kind of got it working, but I feel like there is a much better way, than just updating the inline `transform` style for each bubble. It doesn't feel quite as natural as I'd expect it to.

I've also tried a "hacky" way with [`scroll-snap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_scroll_snap), but I couldn't quite get it to work.

Ideally, I'd love a pure CSS solution, but I'll take what I can get. Is the below approach most likely the only one I can use?

```js
const { createRoot } = ReactDOM;
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;

const createSwipeHandlers = ({
  leftSwipeHandler,
  swipeStopHandler,
  minSwipeDist = 5
}) => {
  let xDown = null;
  let yDown = null;

  return {
    mouseStart: ((e) => {
      xDown = e.clientX;
      yDown = e.clientY;
    }),
    mouseMove: (e) => {
      if (!xDown || !yDown) return;

      const xUp = e.clientX;
      const yUp = e.clientY;

      const xDiff = xDown - xUp;
      const xDiffAbs = Math.abs(xDiff);
      const yDiff = yDown - yUp;
      const yDiffAbs = Math.abs(yDiff);

      if (xDiffAbs > yDiffAbs && xDiff > 0 && xDiffAbs > minSwipeDist) {
        leftSwipeHandler(xDiffAbs);
      }
    },
    mouseOut: (e) => {
      xDown = null;
      yDown = null;
    },
    mouseStop: (e) => {
      xDown = null;
      yDown = null;
      swipeStopHandler(e);
    }
  };
};

const BubbleRow = React.memo(
  ({
    messageText,
    setSelectedMessage,
    isLastBubble
  }) => {
    const bubbleRef = React.useRef(null);

    const handleLeftSwipe = React.useCallback((dist) => {
      if (bubbleRef.current) {
        if (dist > 72) {
          bubbleRef.current.style.transform = null;
          setSelectedMessage(messageText);
          return;
        }

        bubbleRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(-${dist}px)`;
      }
    }, []);

    const { mouseStart, mouseMove, mouseOut, mouseStop } = createSwipeHandlers({
      leftSwipeHandler: handleLeftSwipe,
      swipeStopHandler: (e) => {
        if (bubbleRef.current) {
          //@ts-expect-error
          bubbleRef.current.style.transform = null;
        }
      }
    });

    const className = `row${isLastBubble ? " last-bubble-row" : ""}`;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <div
          ref={bubbleRef}
          className={"bubble"}
          onMouseDown={mouseStart}
          onMouseMove={mouseMove}
          onMouseOut={mouseOut}
          onMouseLeave={mouseStop}
          onMouseUp={mouseStop}
        >
          {messageText}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

const Footer = React.memo(
  ({
    selectedMessage,
    setSelectedMessage
  }) => {
    const clearSelectedMessage = React.useCallback(() => {
      setSelectedMessage(null);
    }, []);

    if (!selectedMessage) return null;

    return (
      <div key={selectedMessage} className="footer">
        <span>{selectedMessage}</span>
        <span onClick={clearSelectedMessage} className="clear-button">
          {"×"}
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
);

const numberOfChatBubbles = 5;

const App = () => {
  const [selectedMessage, setSelectedMessage] = React.useState(
    null
  );

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="container">
        {Array.from({ length: numberOfChatBubbles }, (_, index) => (
          <BubbleRow
            key={index}
            messageText={`Text for message ${index + 1}`}
            setSelectedMessage={setSelectedMessage}
            isLastBubble={index + 1 === numberOfChatBubbles}
          />
        ))}
        <Footer
          selectedMessage={selectedMessage}
          setSelectedMessage={setSelectedMessage}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<StrictMode><App /></StrictMode>);
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.bubble {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 3px 12px;
  transition: 0.04s linear;
  height: fit-content;
  user-select: none;
}

.last-bubble-row {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@keyframes blinkFade {
  0%,
  100% {
    filter: brightness(1);
  }

  20% {
    filter: brightness(0.4);
  }
}

.footer {
  height: 64px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  animation: blinkFade 1.5s;
  background-color: gray;
}

.clear-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Currently looks like this:

[image: gif]

Comment: I think updating the `transform` style is fine. It might be worth describing what "natural" feels to you, potentially adding an example from a different app.

Comment: My thoughts, after comparing with another app are: (1) The message should only be returned to its original position after the user has released the mouse. Right now it returns after the mouse moves out of the message. However this means the user has to be precise in their movement – they don't have much room to move the mouse up or down and they can't move the mouse faster than the element moves. (2) The max horizontal distance seems really small. (3) There needs to be a signal that the movement is reaching the limit of movement. For example, slowing down the transition and adding elasticity.

Comment: Use RAF in combination with your transition for smoother animation. `transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;transform: translateX(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You done really great.But there is one more optimized solution with pure css. You can create a div with your bubble, and that div should be resizable. Make that div to be transparent. And your message containg div will be resizable icon for that. On which dragging the size of div changes and your div will also move horizontally. For reference, i am adding a link. You can read this article and get a clear idea that how to do so. https://css-tricks.com/books/greatest-css-tricks/draggable-elements/

Comment: In the article you linked, it says: "If you actually need to do something as a result of that dragging, your back in JavaScript territory." So, although it's a clever solution, I don't think that it fits my use case, unfortunately

Comment: Have you maybe considered using react-swipeable? 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable